# AIP conference proceedings template - issue with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I'm currently using the `aip-cp.cls` class file for generating an AIP conference paper using LaTeX. In general, everything is working fine apart from the references which are generated at the end of the `.pdf` output file.

I am using a BibTeX database to produce my bibliography in conjunction with the `aipnum-cp` bibliography style which is recommended by AIP. This generates numbered style references according to `natbib`.

The issue I am having is that the reference list outputted in the `.pdf` file is not complete. For all `@article` entries, the journal paper title is missing. Everything else is included. This anomaly does not occur for `@inproceedings` or `@book` entries. I'm at a loss as to what is causing this so I'm hoping someone can assist.

Comment: Apologies, should have included that info. Yes, class file is available for download here: http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/info/authors

Answer (score 2):

The steps are:

1. Open the "aipnum-cp.bst" file
2. In the row 2637 type "format.title output"

Thats all